Excel extracting numbers from within a string/cell
Is there a way in Excel to extract the first six numbers after a pattern of characters?
For example, the pattern would be abc:
abc123456
abc/123456
ABC 123456
test_abc12345679
abc123456 abc56789
12abc123456

The formula should return 123456 for all of the above.

The latest Excel version added support for REGEXEXTRACT, which allows us to use a simple regex to extract the 6 digits:
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "\d{6}"; 1)

Where the 1 return mode flag means: 'Return All Matches'
Result in first column

For matching the abc pattern, we can define all allowed chars in the pattern (abc, /, \,  ) before matching the 6 digits.
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "[abcABC\\ \/]+?(\d{6})"; 2)

We use return mode 2 to return only the capture group ((\d{6}))
Result in second column



Requires the following (Beta) Excel versions:

Windows: Version 2406 (Build 17715.20000) or later
Mac: Version 16.86 (Build 24051422) or later


The only answer worth upvoting as it's using RegExtract.  Otherwise a search for [excel] extract numbers on SO returns 1,124 results

I've added a second regex that only matches after the pattern

@MayukhBhattacharya.  I haven't got REGEXTRACT on this computer so couldn't test, but seemed to work.  I found this answer by some guy called Mayukh Bhattacharya that almost works - How to extract numbers with separation in Excel.  I haven't looked at every result the search returned - no doubt some of them don't work.

Try something along the lines which follows the pattern abc:


=LET(
     a, A1:A7,
     b, MID(a,SEARCH("abc*",a)+{3,4},{6,7}),
     --BYROW(IFERROR(b/(LEN(--b)=6),""),CONCAT))


Or:
=LET(
     a, A1:A7,
     b, MID(a,SEARCH("abc*",a)+{3,4,5},6),
     BYROW(b/(LEN(--b)=6),LAMBDA(r,@TOROW(r,3))))



Try this formula. It might help
=IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")),6)), LOOKUP(2,1/--MID(A1,MIN(INDEX(FIND(ROW($1:$10)-1,A1&1/17),,)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))))



I used this formula to get it to work:-
=LOOKUP(10^6,1*MID(B2,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},B2&"0123456789",FIND("NBU"," "&B2&" "))),{2,3,4,5,6}))


The formula is in cell D35
The pattern is in cell D34
=LET(cont,SEARCH(UPPER($D$34),UPPER(A35))+3,
err,ISERROR(cont),
res,IF(NOT(err),MID(A35,cont,999)),
fin,MID(res,SEQUENCE(LEN(res)),1),
fina,LEFT(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(fin)),fin,"")),6),
IF(LEN(fina)>5,fina,""))




SEARCH not require UPPER function. Can be left.
